# Sparkfun Ethernet Shield knocks out upload to board sync, though it worked before

Tags: arduino, synchronization, ethernet, avrdude

Existing Arduino project uses Arduino brand Duemilanove and Ethernet shield. It has worked well in operation for 4yrs (!) and then through a period of revisions I've been making just recently.  I'm putting it back into service, but want to continue development, so have acquired an Uno board (with identical memory specs to Duemilanove), and a SparkFun Ethernet Shield.

I was able to program the new system fine for many revisions 20-30 times without problems - I'm aware of sync problems if you select the wrong board, so didn't have that problem.

Suddenly though, I get the error:
 avrdude: stk500_getsync(): not in sync: resp=0x00

I checked the board selection of course, and it is fine.  I even tried flipping it back and forth, and restarting the Arduino 1.0.5 IDE just in case, but I can't get sync anymore.

I've not being doing anything challenging with the code -just print statement edits and commenting the code.

HOWEVER - if I unplug the Ethernet Shield it works fine. Sync and load no problem. I can even replace the shield and the software works with the Ethernet still.

Why did it suddenly go south?  Any thought if this is recoverable or should I just return the Sparkfun Shield as defective.

Thx for your input.
Ross.

Comment: Are you uploading using a programmer or via the Arduino's USB port?

Comment: I'm using the USB port on the Arduino Uno.

Comment: Later: returned the sparkfun shield and got an Arduino one, and it allows me to upload again.  Can't think of what went bad on the Sparkfun unit from simple program and upload interactions.